# Object creation with different name

Tags: java

Suppose I'm building a library class to keep track of my book purchases.
I would code something like the following to help me create book objects (don't mind too much about the specifics. This code is just to illustrate my question):

```
public class MyLibrary {

 String bookName = "";
 String bookAuthor = "";
 double purchasePrice = 0.00;
 int printYear = 0;

  public Book(String name, String author, double price, int year) {

   this.bookName = name;
   this.bookAuthor = author;
   this.purchasePrice = price;
   this.printYear = year;
  }    
 }
```

And then I'm thinking of using a Scanner object in the main() parte of the program to help me introduce data and create book objects.
Something like:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Give a book name, please: ");
String bookName = input.next();
.
. (repeat for every other argument)
.
Book book1 = new Book(bookName, etc.,);
```

Now, I created this specific object - book1 - directly inside the code. 
But if I'm letting a user create new books, how can the program create objects with a different name/reference?

In other words, how can I make sure that new objects created by the user will be successively called book1, book2, book3, etc. or some other name choosen by the user?

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `java.util.List<Book>` for that and get the reference by index.

Comment: Why would you want the user to name your internal variables?

Comment: This question goes to some of the basic concepts of programming. If this is part of a course you're taking, I recommend bringing this up with your instructor so that they can consider adjusting their lesson plan.

Comment: Thanks @nathaniel-waisbrot
But I don't have any instructor. I'm just looking at some tutorials and trying to learn something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you create an object with the `new` keyword, you'll have a new book that will replace the previous one. Just be sure to save the previous one before creating the new one.

You can have a look at other answers to understand how to use `Collections` in your program, it's a very important feature in Java. Anyway, when you'll exit your program, **you'll lose all the information**, because Collections save information in memory and memory will be cleaned completely. You'll need a **persistent storage to save information from one execution to another**. Persistent storage are files or databases, for example.

Just try to use first Collections to store and print the list of books. Then you'll implement a persistent storage to save them on disk to be able to retrieve them after stopping and starting again the program.

Comment: Ok. This begins to solve my problem.
Read somewhere in the replies/comments that the name of the reference is irrelevant. 
But I thought class methods are acessed through objects. If I write something like book1.getName(); it's through the object's 'book1' reference that I can invoke that information, right?
If all the objects are called 'book1', how will the program knows how to return the right book?

Comment: Just add each book in a Collection before asking for the next one. Once all the books are in the Collection, you'll be able to implement a search algorithm to retrieve one particular book.

Comment: @Toscano You are correct as far as you go. In addition, `book1` refers to *one* `Book` object at a time, so when you do `book1.getName()`, you call the `getName()` method on whichever `Book` `book1` refers to **at that exact moment**. When you create a new `Book` object (`book1= new Book(...);`), subsequent calls are directed to the new object. As this answer and others suggest, you should look at the Collections framework. These built-in classes provide very useful ways to store multiple objects in your program.

Comment: Thanks, @code-guru
That was helpful. I'll have a look into those Collections.

Answer (score 3):

Just store them in a `HashMap<String,Book>` and use the Book's name as your key.  That way fetching a book by title becomes easy

Here are the different steps you need:

Creation of the Map

```
Map <String,Book> bookMap = new HashMap<String,Book>();
```

Adding a book to the Map:

```
String bookName = input.next();
Book book1 = new Book(bookName, etc.,);
bookMap.put(bookName,book1);
```

Then get the book out of the map by title:

```
Book foundBook = bookMap.get(bookName);
```

Getting a list of books stored in the maps can be done via the [keySet method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29):

```
for (String title : bookMap.keySet()) {
    ...
}
```

The [Oracle tutorial on Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) is a great place to start learning more, Collections are really very important in almost all programs, it's quite useful to learn to exploit all their possibilities.

EDIT: just to clarify a bit where I want to point you with my answer: Java doesn't allow you to dynamically create names for objects (identifiers cannot pop up all of a sudden during runtime).  When you want to create and keep (store) objects dynamically, you use one of the Collection types offered by Java.  There's a wide selection of Collection types in the standard API, a quick intro to the offered "subfamilies" can be found [in the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html).  Now, because I assumed you would want to search your stored items by the attribute entered by the user, I proposed to use a Map, using the book's title as key.  Of course you could have picked a List, but in a List items are numbered, and a search by title would force you to iterate over the List and inspect each stored item's title until you have found the correct book.  In many cases that's not very efficient, and it forces you to write more code.

That doesn't mean that you should use HashMap's for *everything*.  Quite the contrary, you need to understand the strengths and weaknesses of all offered interfaces to be able to write optimal code.  I hope my post pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Provide more code to show your example. Looks like OP doesn't know how to handle this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ok, give me a minute

Comment: I think OP don't know collections (very well).

Comment: @JimmyT then this is the perfect time to learn about them :-)  No seriously, I think mastering Collections is important enough to learn about them as quickly as possible, and especially if they can help you solving the problem you're having quickly and elegantly.

Comment: I think OP is trying to create new variables or why should they be called book1, and so on?

Comment: If he wants to get multiple books I can only assume he wants to store them somewhere.  If the number of books is not known initially, he'll never be able to create an appropriate number of objects to store them, and that's exactly why collections are used.  I show him (Hash)Map because a) it solves his problem by offering an elastic container for "any" number of books and b) it's searchable by title, something that requires a lot of extra programming when you use say a List (you have to iterate over the List and inspect each stored element's title separately.

Comment: Thanks, everyone ( @jimmy-t ). Indeed, I don't know much about collections. Just starting out.
Read somewhere in other comments above that the reference name is irrelevant to the object creation. 
My persisting doubt is that I thought class methods are acessed through specific objects. 
If I write something like book1.getName(); it's through the object's 'book1' reference that I can invoke that information, right? 
If all the objects are called 'book1', how will the program know how to return the right book name? It's just this part that I can't get my head around...

Comment: @Toscano `getName()` does not return 'book1'

Comment: Note that there might be different books with the same title. In this case, using a Map (with book titles as keys) would not work well.

Comment: @tobias_k  Sigh... :-) Well in that case OP can 1) select a better key or 2) use a Map<String title,Map<String author, Book book>> or 3) switch to [a MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html).

Comment: It looks like an easy practice to start learning collections :)

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I think I got the gist of it.

So an object identifier (in my example, 'book1') only relates to the last created object, or actual object in memory. 
What I gather from this is that creating a new object will erase the reference going from the identifier 'book1' to the previous object, which better be saved somewhere to avoid disappointment (and general consensus leads me to believe I should start looking into Collections to achieve that).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you cannot name it Book1,Book2,... but you might use array of book objects but that 'll limit you in size. use it as Book[index]

```
Book[] books = new Book[10];
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    books[i] = new Book( ... ); //process book object
```

**Maybe you could keep Arraylist of Book.**

```
ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
```

arraylist's more flexible.

you can add objects

```
 books.add(new Book(...));
```

access Books using iterator or with an Index

```
 books.get(index);  //more better than Book1,Book2, ...
```

you get a book from Books.

Comment: So just using this line of code will magically solve all the problems?

Comment: So first you show how to use an `ArrayList` but discard this solution and prefer to use your own manually handed array? Sorry to give you a hard-time, but really this is not a proper good solution. The fact that it can solve it doesn't mean the solution is well designed.

Comment: Downvote is great if downvoter lets me know what am i missing or wrong! so that everyone can learn!

Answer (score 1):

You need two things: A loop, and a list (or another sort of collection), for example:

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    // ... ask title, author, etc.
    Book book = new Book(bookName, etc.,);
    books.add(book);
}
```

Note that this will run in an infinite loop. You will also need to add some exit condition. Either ask the user how many books to add before entering the loop, or use a `break` statement to exit the loop once the user enters some special key word, like "exit".

Afterwards, you can use another loop to search for and access books stored in that list:

```
for (Book book : books) {
    // do stuff with book, e.g. print its title
    System.our.println(book.getTitle());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the reference is irrelevant.

You can do this:

```
while reading user input {
    Book book = new Book(bookName, etc.,);
    storeTheBook(book);
}

private void storeTheBook(Book book) {
    // Store it wherever you want.
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really have any more information than the question.